# Android Instant apps play video fail, show "Can't play this video."

Tags: android-videoview, android-instant-apps

(Instant apps can play video normally use webview, but videoview fail.

Use Android Videoview play video, The APK can play normally, but the Instant apps can not play. show error: Can't play this video.

java code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://v1-tt.ixigua.com/40f0bfa756a159d27864bb70aeabdb8b/59f457f6/video/m/22033a84279cb1145a8bafee6279724505b1151dcf0000063157252c98c/");
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

logcat show:

> 10-28 06:31:01.952 21522-21522/? W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open
>   https://v1-tt.ixigua.com/40f0bfa756a159d27864bb70aeabdb8b/59f457f6/video/m/22033a84279cb1145a8bafee6279724505b1151dcf0000063157252c98c/:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   https://v1-tt.ixigua.com/40f0bfa756a159d27864bb70aeabdb8b/59f457f6/video/m/22033a84279cb1145a8bafee6279724505b1151dcf0000063157252c98c/
>   10-28 06:31:01.953 21522-21522/? V/MediaHTTPService:
>   MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@79aba57): Cookies:
>   null 10-28 06:31:01.954 21522-21522/? E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to
>   create media player 10-28 06:31:01.958 21522-21522/? W/VideoView:
>   Unable to open content:
>   https://v1-tt.ixigua.com/40f0bfa756a159d27864bb70aeabdb8b/59f457f6/video/m/22033a84279cb1145a8bafee6279724505b1151dcf0000063157252c98c/
>                                                 java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
>                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
>                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1153)
>                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1141)
>                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
>                                                     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1080)
>                                                     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:399)
>                                                     at android.widget.VideoView.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                     at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:678)
>                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:664)
>                                                     at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:143)
>                                                     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
>                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2337)
>                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
>                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
>                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 10-28
>   06:31:01.958 21522-21522/? D/VideoView: Error: 1,0

Comment: Instead of using Uri.parse to set the URL, try using the videoView.setVideoPath as have been used in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435356).

Comment: No effect, the same error

Comment: @m41m41 please have a look on this link might it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433248/play-video-from-url-in-videoview-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: setVideoPath, the same error

Comment: @m41m41, Incase the problem is still not solved, I would suggest you to file a bug and see if Google can assist you. Also, please share link to your bug back in here so it would be helpful for all. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787
TIP: Google might need sample project/Instant Application (with this issue) to provide a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error does not seem to be related to Android Instant Apps, since playing a video in this manner works.

I'm getting a 403 error when trying to access [the video you provided](https://v1-tt.ixigua.com/40f0bfa756a159d27864bb70aeabdb8b/59f457f6/video/m/22033a84279cb1145a8bafee6279724505b1151dcf0000063157252c98c/).

Make sure that accessing the video's file access is correct for the app's user.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the link. At the same time, The APK can play normally, but the Instant apps can not play.